# Hair particles look different in object mode than in particle edit more

Tags: particles, hair

I added a plane to the scene, then added a new particle system for hair and this is how the particles look:

[image]

They should be straight lines but aren't for some reason, but when I go into particle edit mode they look like this:

[image]

Which is the correct way I want them to look. So why do they look messed up in the object mode?

I tried opening a new empty blender scene, adding a plane with hair particle system and it looked correctly there, particles looked like the second picture in both object mode and particle edit mode. Which means this problem exists only in my current scene. What could be causing this?

Thank you

Comment: If you just added the _Particle System_ and did not change anything of the defaults, it is strange that they look like that. In case you did change anything - would it be asked too much if you show some screenshots of the settings? Some things like settings for _Children_ hair particles can change the look in _Object Mode_ (like _Clumping_  or _Kink_ for example) but that has no effect on the parent particles which are the only ones you can edit in _Particle Edit_ mode so there they are still straight. Maybe upload the file here and follow the instructions there: https://blend-exchange.com

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann I didn't touch any settings, simply clicked + to add particle system and thats it. Are there maybe some global particle settings in blender that affect all particle systems? Sadly I I can't upload this particular file.

Comment: Any other file where you have similar problems which you can upload? Is there a force field in your scene like wind or anything? Otherwise I'm afraid there is not much we can do, your screenshots don't show anything relevant, no settings, not what else is in the scene that could have an influence... so without any information or the file to check what is going on there it would all be just wild guessing. Did you delete the particle system and added a new one and did it have the same problem?

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Thats it! I have a wind force field in the scene for the smoke simulation, and I completely forgot that force fields also affect  hair particles. If you post it as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: You can actually post an answer to your own question and even accept it after a grace period. That would be best because in the answer you could show screenshots of that force field in your scene and how it affects the hair.